# How can I copy the filtered range without the headers and paste it into another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, filter

This is what I have so far, and would like to paste it into another sheet.

```
    Sheets("CDGL Data").Select
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=32, Criteria1:= _
        "*13725*"
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
```

I don't want to copy the headers which start in A1

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty, but it's effective.

```
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.rows.Count - 1).Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: I expect this could go sideways if there was other data on the worksheet...